# Overlapping of audio

Tags: python, concurrency, alsa

I am working on a project to play a audio playback once motion is detected. I am using the motion.conf script and Raspberry Pi to do it.

Everything is working fine, however once 2 consecutive motion is detected, the same audio are played and overlapped which cause a very loud and muffled audio.
Does anyone know of any python script that can queue the audios and play it one by one?

My current on_motion_detected line is as followed:

```
on_motion_detected aplay greeting.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

The default ALSA device uses the `dmix` plugin to allow multiple applications to share the same output device.

If you do not actually want this, you can bypass this by directly playing to some other device, such as `plughw`:

```
aplay -D plughw greeting.wav
```

In this case, opening the device will wait until it is available.